# Why this np.where(x == np.array([1,2,3])) is returning an empty tuple?

Tags: python

Let x = np.array([9323, 11939,   231, ...,  5192, 12172,   235
]). How I suppose to get all the different indexes in np.where(x == [0,1,2,3,4,5...9323]) ??

The command below is giving me an empty tuple :

```
np.where(x == np.array([1,2,3]))
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

I have to find all the exact indexes(position) for:

```
x == [0:max(x)]
```

please help...

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're comparing equal sized arrays.

Comment: `==` isn't a containment test. It doesn't test whether the elements of an array appear in another array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [np.in1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.3/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> np.in1d(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]*20), np.array([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the goal is to find WHERE exactly is the position of each one. So if I am gonna use your solution with the above command I have to give TRUE and FALSE some values. Because I have to find in 
      x=np.array([1,5,7,2,8,0,6,3,4])
      np.where(x == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
And as an output I have to get this : 5 , 0 , 3 , 7 , 8 , 1 , 6

Comment: `x=np.in1d(a,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]); np.where(x==True)`